# DNS connection - digital digitalocean vps - cant seem to get a domain connection

Tags: django, dns, cloud, vps, digital-ocean

I'm trying to hook up my domain name to my VPS at digitalocean, and from whois and ping it looks like the domain should have propagated, and has the right nameservers etc. but still wont resolve...
the dns configuration should be good...
not sure what is going on

the server itself does work, and the Django initial page comes up:

```
http://104.131.135.248:8000/ 

Whois Server Version 2.0


   Domain Name: WORDINTEL.COM
   Registrar: ENOM, INC.
   Whois Server: whois.enom.com
   Referral URL: http://www.enom.com
   Name Server: NS1.DIGITALOCEAN.COM
   Name Server: NS2.DIGITALOCEAN.COM
   Name Server: NS3.DIGITALOCEAN.COM
   Status: clientTransferProhibited
   Updated Date: 30-jul-2014
   Creation Date: 30-jul-2014
   Expiration Date: 30-jul-2016

ping wordintel.com
PING wordintel.com (104.131.135.248): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 104.131.135.248: icmp_seq=0 ttl=52 time=31.271 ms
64 bytes from 104.131.135.248: icmp_seq=1 ttl=52 time=54.942 ms
64 bytes from 104.131.135.248: icmp_seq=2 ttl=52 time=35.154 ms
```

[image: control panel dns]

[image: control panel dns 2]

[image: web page not available]

Comment: don't you have to put wordintel.com:8000 in your browser based on your http://104.131.135.248:8000/ ?

Comment: Ok it seems that this is a default port issue http://wordintel.com:8000 resolves fine.

I'll just have to figure out the next part.

Comment: What is the next issue?

Comment: From here it's figuring out nginx and Django setup - I managed to configure the server to point at the domain

Comment: Do I deserve a bit of credit?

Comment: Put in an answer and I'll see about selecting it  - I don't think you can select a comment - thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't you have to put wordintel.com:8000 in your browser based on your 104.131.135.248:8000. Also, check out this video on Django and Nginx setup https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KSGtTbsKUNQ. I hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Ok it seems that this is a default port issue http://wordintel.com:8000 resolves fine.

I'll just have to figure out the next part.